# How to lowercase string value in R?

Tags: r, string, dplyr

**I have a data frame that looks as such:**

```
                                          files
       MVNDR_10055_WESTERN FOREST PRODUCTS.PDF
     MVNDR_102182_BLACK AND DECKER US INC..PDF
      MVNDR_10363_SPRAY AND FORGET        .PDF
```

How do I extract the "PDF" into another column in the data frame and then lowercase it? My idea is then to concatenate afterwards which shouldn't be an issue using paste0.

**Ideal result would look as as such:**

```
                                      files     Lowercase 
   MVNDR_10055_WESTERN FOREST PRODUCTS.PDF         pdf
 MVNDR_102182_BLACK AND DECKER US INC..PDF         pdf
  MVNDR_10363_SPRAY AND FORGET        .PDF         pdf
```

**Eventually the goal is for the table to look like this.**

```
                                      files
   MVNDR_10055_WESTERN FOREST PRODUCTS.pdf
 MVNDR_102182_BLACK AND DECKER US INC..pdf
  MVNDR_10363_SPRAY AND FORGET        .pdf
```

**Note the lowercase "pdf"**

Comment: do you know the function `tolower()`?

Comment: `stringr::str_extract(files, ".{3}$") |> tolower()`

Comment: Would I use this within the mutate verb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `gsubfn` from `gsubfn` and say `tolower` everything after the last dot like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(files = c("MVNDR_10055_WESTERN FOREST PRODUCTS.PDF",
                           "MVNDR_102182_BLACK AND DECKER US INC..PDF",
                           "MVNDR_10363_SPRAY AND FORGET        .PDF"))

library(gsubfn)
#> Loading required package: proto
df$files <- gsubfn(".[^.]+$", tolower, df$files)
df
#>                                       files
#> 1   MVNDR_10055_WESTERN FOREST PRODUCTS.pdf
#> 2 MVNDR_102182_BLACK AND DECKER US INC..pdf
#> 3  MVNDR_10363_SPRAY AND FORGET        .pdf
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see, the extension (.pdf) is now in lowercase.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, That is true, I changed it to the last everything after the last dot. Thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

R already has functions that work with file name extensions:

- `tools::file_path_sans_ext`
- `tools::file_ext`

So you can combine them:

```
df |>
    mutate(files = paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(files), ".", tolower(tools::file_ext(files))))
```

However, these functions are somewhat buggy so if you’re already using the Tidyverse, I suggest using ‘fs’ functions instead:

```
df |>
    mutate(files = fs::path_ext_set(files, tolower(fs::path_ext(files))))
```